Different array between cmd and Chrome console.log()
I'm trying to do an app that fetches data from an API. When I use my API, all the data are there:
API Data from DataBase
But when I'm trying to fetch all those data from my Next.js app, I get 2 different results:

The VS Code console result (only the 3 first row of my array):
VS Code console Result

And Chrome inpection tool result:
Chrome result


But I don't know why on my app I can have access only at the 3 first row even if Chrome show all of them.
Function from page.js:
export default async function Home() {
  const data = await User();
  console.log(data);
  return (
     <h1>Hello</h1>
)}

User function:
export default async function User() {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/getAllPlayers')
    
    return res.json()
}

I already tried to modify my fetch function, but I don't see a lot of problems like mine online.

You should experiment and gather some more info. For instance, print the size of the underlying array, and try printing the elements individually (to exclude the case of VS code potentially mucking with the output). If you find you truly have a different input, you'd have to track that further (perhaps the two pieces of code are loading different json files? Are these run on the same machine?)

Ok I just add cache: "no-store" in fetch function and that works !
